# Keeping consistency across multiple instances of a game running at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a text based browser rpg and I've stumbled into a bit of a problem and am not sure how to proceed. How do you keep consistency across multiple instances of the game running at the same time?? I don't know the technical term for doing this, but for example....

Say a user is playing the game in one window. He/She is presented with the hyperlink "Open Blue Door" which will load a new screen of the game. Say the user opens that link in a new window. There will now be two instances of the game running, and it would be possible to play the game along one storyline in one window and play the game along another completely seperate storyline in the other window. In other words, there would be two instances of the game running at the same time and they would be inconsistent.

Or another example is if a user is in the middle of a game, opens a new window, goes to the website and hits play, it should go directly to where the user is in the other window and not start a new game.

I apologise if this is a noob question and thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle the game's content. I had a similar problem in the past, my solution was to have a single `area` (or `level` if you prefer) and the players were the ones to make the changes but not like an instance; the area remained the same, that `blue door` could actually opened and closed many times by all players (in example) but only once at a time. (via `ajax` etc.) and the players actually were able to see that because i was sending a signal that `blue door` opened (by `ajax` again by polling the server every X seconds).

Comment: You should prevent the user from taking actions if they are not valid to take from their current state, by checking what is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sychronize those events on a Server.  For example, You make an AJAX call to your server, which writes to a table, what doors have been opened, and what the player states are, and where they're located.

You can pole for data using long polling or short polling (look them up).

Or even better, Use firebase!!  Firebase is a service that lets you synchronize data between multiple end points, in the browser.  I've used firebase in the past, it's pretty impressive:

https://www.firebase.com/